# MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 no solution

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am getting the following error when trying to connect to a MongoDB server:
I have checked the following:

- The MongoDB server is running and listening on port 27017.
- The client is using the correct connection string.
- The client is allowed to connect to the MongoDB server on port 27017.
- The firewall is not blocking connections to the MongoDB server.

I am still getting the error. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this?

```
D:\Web-Devlopment-BootCamp-Angela-Yu\FruitProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:278
                const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);
                                     ^

MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (D:\Web-Devlopment-BootCamp-Angela-Yu\FruitProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:278:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 96606451,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (D:\Web-Devlopment-BootCamp-Angela-Yu\FruitProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:367:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Web-Devlopment-BootCamp-Angela-Yu\FruitProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:290:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

Connected successfully to server

Comment: Can you show the connection code? It's likely using the wrong address. You assert a lot of things here that, if true, would mean it's fine, so some of those assertions must be false.